# Open/Libre Office API replace image

Tags: java, api, openoffice.org, libreoffice, uno

I am using LibreOffice 4 and Java Uno API for managing documents.

I've got situation where I am importing HTML documents with img tags to LibreOffice via Java Uno API and save document in other formats (such as odt, docx, doc, rtf).

The problem is that LibreOffice converts img tags to graphic objects with links (not embedded in document).

I was trying to use html base64 but it seems that LibreOffice doesn't support that.

Now I want to convert these linked graphic objects to embedded graphics objects.
I am able to iterate through images via XTextGraphicObjectsSupplier but I can't figure it out how to make these objects embedded.

Is it possible?

Maybe it is possible to make some magic attribute in html img tag and LibreOffice will embed it?

Comment: Add the code that you are using to insert the image if you want somebody to help.

Comment: Have you read what I wrote? I ask how to replace image. This doesn't have anything to do with inserting image. If you have document (for example odt) and in this documents are graphic objects with links (not embedded) then the question is: how to make this linked objects to be embedded? I think there is no need to place code for insterting any images (in fact this is done by LibreOffice transparently - I don't instert images from code).

Comment: Ok, lets try again. I don't know if you understand me. I know how to insert images via openoffice/libreoffice java API. This is not the case. In odt, doc, docx formats you can have pictures storing in two ways: embedded images in odt/doc/docx file or only like links (e.g. http links, file links). The problem is this: I have odt file with pictures which have links to real data (not embedded in odt file). Now I want to make some oprations which will make this pictures embedded. I ask if you know the code for that. The code for inserting images, which I can paste here, is not necessary here.

Comment: So if you don't have solution, then stop writing not useful comments. I know that this is programming site, but surprise: some questions may be added without placing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that libre/open office doesn't support this option. Only way is to remove and again insert embedded image, but you must be aware of formating (e.g. size etc.). I achieved my goal by doing these steps (WARN it is hack...):

1. Save HTML to odt. In this odt graphics are linked to files on disk.
2. Unzip odt file.
3. Create directory `Pictures` in unzipped directory and move there all images.
4. Edit `content.xml` and replace path to system files to `Pictures/file-name`.
5. Edit `META-INF/manifest.xml` and something like this `<manifest:file-entry manifest:media-type="image/png" manifest:full-path="Pictures/file-name"/>`
6. Zip folder and change extension to odt.
7. Read odt file via Libre/Open Office Java Uno API. Now this document has embedded graphic objects.